# Gridview setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE) does not work

Tags: android, gridview

Clicking on an element does not click on other elements.I used myGridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE)but it does not work.

```
    GridView gridView = (GridView)_view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    GridViewAdapter adapter = GridViewAdapter(getActivity(),getList());

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    gridView.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```